# How do I create and save file from stream on FTP folder directly?

Tags: c#, csv, ftp, c#-3.0, ftpwebrequest

I want to generate file dynamically and save that file on FTP folder location

I tried like following.
I do not want to save file locally and then upload it on FTP location.

I have stream and want to create file on ftp using that stream.

how can i do so?

```
  FtpWebRequest requestFileUpload = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" +ftpServerIP+ "/" + remoteDir);
                    requestFileUpload.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
                    requestFileUpload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                    // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
                    StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(FILEDATA);
                    //FILEDATA is nothing but string
                    byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                    sourceStream.Close();
                    requestFileUpload.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                    Stream requestStream = requestFileUpload.GetRequestStream();
                    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                    requestStream.Close();

                    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileUpload.GetResponse();


                    response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I understood you correctly.

You got the FTPWebResponse object called response. You can call GetResponseStream() function for the FTPWebResponse object. This function will give you the stream that you can use to make the actual FTP transfer. 
Than just write a copy function that copies from your sourceStream StreamReader to a Stream.

Example:

```
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileUpload.GetResponse();

Stream myFTPStream = response.GetResponseStream();

//copy data into stream

response.Close();
```

Of course you also need to check for exceptiont and so on. I also did not check the rest of your code but if it works fine so far, this is how you get the desired stream.